# Edward James McShane, books

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request

I looking for book Edward James McShane Integration 1944 year. I need page 188-210 to my bibliography (dini derivatives). Can someone help me and share with me these page ?. I tried buy this book but unfortunately I can't find her anywhere. HELP. :)

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Integration-Princeton-Legacy-Library-McShane/dp/0691652147/ref=tmm_hrd_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1584568316&sr=8-2 You can buy used one (new are not in stock)

Comment: destination day is 14-16 :/. and my promoter want this book now. But thanks you for information. If no one can help i will buy this one :).

Comment: Is it not sufficient to download the PDF from [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.212218/)?